# Error Percentage in SQL

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

Below it the table which contains Actual Count and Error Count for each ID.

```
USER_ID    |    Actual_Count    |   Error_Count
-----------+--------------------+---------------------
1345653         5                     4
534140349       5                     0
682527813       4                     0
687612723       3                     0
704318001       5                     4
```

So if you look at the above scenario, For this `1345653` ID Out of `5`, it has `4` errors, same with `704318001` ID, out of `5` it has `4` errors. And all other ID's they didn't have any errors as `Error_Count` is `Zero` for them. How can I calculate the total error percentage in SQL? Is it possible to calculate the total error percentage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply sum and divide the individual counts:

```
SELECT 100 * sum(Error_Count) / sum(Actual_Count) FROM MyTable;
```

This will not work in all databases,  because some (such as SQL Server) do integer division.  The following does work:

```
SELECT 100 * sum(Error_Count*1.0) / sum(Actual_Count) FROM MyTable;
```